# Hammer events delegation and reuse of backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, hammer.js

## Edit

According the `Hammer` [`Github page`](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/766) this bug was due to `Manager` leaks and should be fixed in the `2.0.5` version - this version is not built online but one can built it by himself. More info can be found [here](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/766)

## =====================================================

## Original question:

## =====================================================

We are using [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org) with [Hammer 2](http://hammerjs.github.io/),[backbone hammer plugin](https://github.com/wookiehangover/backbone.hammer) and 
[hammer jquery plugin](http://hammerjs.github.io/jquery-plugin/).

### The issue

when working with `domEvents` and only 1 copy of `A` view it works fine.

But, when doing something like

```
var first = new A();
var second = new A();
```

hammer listeners do not work on the second view.

`note`:
When adding `click` event to the list above, the click is being fired on both `first` and `second` views. So this something with hammer events and events delegations.

Any ideas how to overcome this issue ?

Thanks!

Oak

### P.S Some code (run-able in stack-overflow)

Here is some code example. As can be seen - swiperight only works on the first view and not on the second. The code use [touch emulator](http://hammerjs.github.io/touch-emulator/) so one can check it with mouse as well.

```js
A = Backbone.View.extend({

  hammerEvents: {

    "panstart .js-feed-btn": "_onPan",
    "panmove .js-feed-btn": "_onPan",
    "swiperight .js-feed-btn": "_onSwipeRight",
    "click .js-feed-btn-clickable": "_onClick"

  },

  hammerOptions: {
    //tap: true,
    domEvents: true
  },

  _onPan: function(e) {
    this.$el.find('.status-bar').html('panning... ' + this.cid);
    var view = this;
    if (this._animate) {
      return;
    }
    snabbt(e.target, {

      position: [e.originalEvent.gesture.deltaX / 2, 0, 0],
      duration: 100,
      callback: function() {
        this._animate = false;
      }

    })

  },

  _onSwipeRight: function(e) {
    snabbt(e.target, {
      position: [e.originalEvent.gesture.deltaX, 0, 0],

    }).then({
      position: [0, 0, 0]
    })


    this.$el.find('.status-bar').html('swiperight ' + this.cid);

  },


  _onClick: function() {
    this.$el.find('.status-bar').html('clicked ' + this.cid);
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html('<div class="js-feed-btn">swipe me right</div><div class="js-feed-btn-clickable">clickme</div><section class="status-bar"></section>');
    return this;
  },

});


var first = new A();
var second = new A();

var parent = new Backbone.View();
parent.$el.append(first.render().$el)
parent.$el.append(second.render().$el)
  //$('.app').html(first.render().$el)
  //$('.app').append(second.render().$el)
$('.app').html(parent.$el)
```

```css
div {
  min-height: 20px;
}
.status-bar {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/hammerjs/touchemulator/master/touch-emulator.js"></script>
<script>
  TouchEmulator();
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jashkenas/underscore/master/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/jashkenas/backbone/master/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/hammerjs/jquery.hammer.js/master/jquery.hammer.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wookiehangover/backbone.hammer/master/backbone.hammer.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/daniel-lundin/snabbt.js/master/snabbt.js"></script>
<section id="main">
  <h3>Simple code</h3>
  <section class="app"></section>

</section>
```

Comment: I first encountered your question looking for answers to something else. I've since refactored my code to use backbone.hammer, and switched from using one Hammer instance in the containing View to setting up Hammer in a sub-View class which is instantiated multiple times. Everything works great in Firefox and Chrome on the desktop, but if use Chrome's dev tools to mimic an iPad (or Nexus, etc.), **or** use a *real* iPad or Nexus 7, I have the exact same problem! Only the first instance works! I've got to get to the bottom of this. Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: A much simpler example (no `jquery.hammer` or `backbone.hammer`)  of this same issue can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016312/multiple-elements-respond-to-touch-event-on-mobile-webkit-and-hammer-js -- unfortunately it, too, is as yet unanswered.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a bug, and I have tracked down the offending code. I will file a bug report and pull request next week (though I am not yet certain that my solution doesn't break something else).

The problem is that Hammer is adding all the listeners to the very first element (which incidentally results in your receiving an event for every element to which you add the recognizer--add 4 `press` listeners, and your callback gets called 4 times for every press).

I've managed to make `press` and `swipe` events work (with touch device emulation via Chrome, as well as a genuine iPad and a Nexus 7). Haven't tested other events yet.

I simply changed line 946 (of Hammer 2.0.4) from

```
this.evTarget = TOUCH_TARGET_EVENTS;
```

to

```
this.evEl = TOUCH_TARGET_EVENTS;
```

Note that you might need to make the same change to line 878, but I haven't actually figured out where, when or if the `SingleTouchInput` class is ever used.

Like I said, I'm not certain that this is a proper fix, but it is certainly a workaround. I'll report back if I discover any problems or undesirable side-effects.

Comment: interesting finding. In fact i have another bug with hammerjs that i haven't post, i haven't tried your fix yet but it seems that it can solves my 2nd bug as well. i'll update on it as soon as i test your fix

Comment: For what it's worth, I haven't filed a bug yet. Once I got this working, my manager asked me to change priorities on this project. I'll look into this again once I get back to work on touch-ifying things.